# Versões do Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou criando um app, só que quando eu fiz o apk ele não funciona da versão 6.0 pra baixo, mas o meu mimSdk esta na 4.3. Já tentei vários metodos que pesquisei mas nenhum funcionou. Queria pedir a ajuda de alguem.

Comment: ola Lucas Daniel Fischer, depende da feature que voce quer utilizar, normalmente as ultimas versoes do android sao retrocompativeis no core mas nao os designs e tal. Aki no no Google Developers voce pode ter uma ideia de qual  versao do Android usar https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/

Answer (score 0):

ola Lucas Daniel Fischer, depende da feature que você quer utilizar, normalmente as ultimas versões do android são retrocompativeis no core mas não os designs e etc. No Google Developers você pode ter uma ideia de qual versão do Android usar [link](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards), provavelmente você não irá precisar voltar tantas versões.